# How come python functions can access variables that are not defined in the arguments?

Tags: python, global-variables

For example if I write

```
a=1
def func():
   return a
func()
```

It will return 1. Is this normal behavior? Are variables supposed to act in a global way in python?

Comment: Actually, it will NOT return anything in your example - because you're not calling the ```func()```    DId you miss it>

Comment: Up-level references are allowed in Python, both globals and variables that are defined in a higher scope (e.g. as in nested functions).  If you don't declare them (with `global` or `nonlocal`), you can still reference them provided the function doesn't assign to them.  If it does, then you need to declare them or else it will create a variable that is local to the function.

Comment: @DanielHao sorry I just ammended my question. could you answer the updated version please

Comment: OK.  Saw a great answer ^^^ already posted by @TomKarzes

Comment: so is it considered bad practice to assign variables with higher scope? Essentially variables are treated as global unless I make them specifically local? @TomKarzes

Comment: @dani - an article for you https://realpython.com/python-scope-legb-rule/

Comment: I would say it's ok if done sparingly, when there's a genuine need.  You probably want to limit the number of functions that modify globals.  Using `nonlocal` to modify variables in the parent scope can sometimes be useful.  Again, I'd use is sparingly, when it's really needed.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm not looking into modifying globals, just accessing them. And a side question, if I have several numpy arrays that I need to define, for example diameter, depth, velocity, size, etc, is there a way to put them all in a struct like Matlab? How do I achieve the same thing in Python? For example accessing them by writing struct1.depth, struct1.diameter etc?

Comment: @dani In Python you'd put them in a class.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a variable with the same name inside a function, this variable will be local, and can only be used inside the function. The global variable with the same name will remain as it was, global and with the original value.

That is the way python language works !

Comment: Thank you that's very helpful. So, essentially, whenever I'm assigning a variable I'm polluting the namespace for all of the sub-functions as well?

Comment: It all depends on the Use Case --- not so much *polluting*

Comment: Yes @dani ! It has avantages too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).